# Require trait implementations to be convertible between each other

Tags: rust

I'm trying to have a Rust trait `X` which requires that anyone implementing `X` can convert to other implementations of `X`.

So I'm trying to make the declaration of `X` enforce this like so:

```
trait X<T> : From<T> where T: X {}
```

But the compiler is telling me that it doesn't find any type arguments in my specification of `T`, because `T: X` needs some type information `T: X<...>`. But this way there will always be one type argument too little; e.g.

```
trait X<T, U> : From<T> where T: X<U> {}
```

Can I get around this in some way? Doing `where T: X<_>` is not allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is supposed to be doing, but `X` isn't a trait: it's a generic that, when you substitute in a type for the `T` parameter, *results* in a trait.  In other words, `T: X` won't work; you need `T: X<Something>` for it to make sense.

Comment: *anyone implementing `X` can convert to other implementations of `X`* Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't this be impossible? You are asking for one type from a possibly infinite set of types has to be convertible to any other type in that set, even if one type was written in a different crate years after the first one?

Comment: @DK Ah yeah, `X` needs a specification too of course when it's a type argument. But if I update the definition to read `trait X<T, U> : From<T> where T: X<U> {}` the compiler still tells me I have too few type arguments. Now it's just expecting two and found only one, as opposed to expecting one and finding zero.

Comment: @Shepmaster My use case is that I have different structs which contain only a number of something, where the struct represents the unit. I want to specify that such a struct should be convertable to any other struct which uses a different unit, where the unit is still the same type. So if someone wants to add a new struct to represent a new type of unit, it should be able to be converted to any of the existing structs.

Comment: I clarified the question based on the discussion here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to restrict the implementers, I think it would be simpler to provide the implementation as part of the trait:

```
trait Length {
    fn unit_in_meters() -> f64;

    fn value(&self) -> f64;
    fn new(value: f64) -> Self;

    fn convert_to<T:Length>(&self) -> T {
        T::new(self.value() * Self::unit_in_meters() / T::unit_in_meters())
    }
}

struct Mm {
    v: f64,
}

impl Length for Mm {
    fn unit_in_meters() -> f64 { 0.001 }

    fn value(&self) -> f64 { self.v }
    fn new(value: f64) -> Mm {
        Mm{ v: value }
    }
}

struct Inch {
    v: f64,
}

impl Length for Inch {
    fn unit_in_meters() -> f64 { 0.0254 }

    fn value(&self) -> f64 { self.v }
    fn new(value: f64) -> Inch {
        Inch{ v: value }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foot = Inch::new(12f64);
    let foot_in_mm: Mm = foot.convert_to();
    println!("One foot in mm: {}", foot_in_mm.value());
}
```

[Play link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6dc78f1da1e53059fced29fe05a7b39a&version=stable&backtrace=0)

For fun, with the `associated_consts` feature you can swap the method for a constant conversion factor.

```
#![feature(associated_consts)]
trait Length {
    const UNIT_IN_METERS: f64;

    fn value(&self) -> f64;
    fn new(value: f64) -> Self;

    fn convert_to<T:Length>(&self) -> T {
        T::new(self.value() * Self::UNIT_IN_METERS / T::UNIT_IN_METERS)
    }
}

struct Mm {
    v: f64,
}

impl Length for Mm {
    const UNIT_IN_METERS: f64 = 0.001;

    fn value(&self) -> f64 { self.v }
    fn new(value: f64) -> Mm {
        Mm{ v: value }
    }
}

struct Inch {
    v: f64,
}

impl Length for Inch {
    const UNIT_IN_METERS: f64 = 0.0254;

    fn value(&self) -> f64 { self.v }
    fn new(value: f64) -> Inch {
        Inch{ v: value }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foot = Inch::new(12f64);
    let foot_in_mm: Mm = foot.convert_to();
    println!("One foot in mm: {}", foot_in_mm.value());
}
```

[Play link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b94654bce949baee39bd46eb47e63970&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

Comment: Oooh, nice! I've toyed with a similar concept (though yours is way nicer), but I dropped it because I didn't want to pay the runtime cost of unnecessary calculations. Do you know if the compiler calculates them when going with the associated const values? I assume the compiler doesn't do so in the first concept at least.

EDIT: Also, do you know if associated_const is a nightly feature since it's gated?

Comment: Yes, the associated_const feature is nightly only at the moment.  I think it optimises relatively well; I can't see any reference to either `convert_to()` or `unit_in_meters()` in the generated ASM in the playpen in release mode.  I can't see any MUL either, so it might all have been constant-evaluated, but I'm a bit rusty on x86 assembly so may have missed something.

Comment: Alright thanks; then your approach is definitely better then what I had going on :)